# font size is not working in my d3.js code

Tags: d3.js

i am writing d3.js for generating many charts and graphs.. but when there is no data i am just appending svg a text and writting "no data to display" and assigning some attributes like x y dy etc.. similarly font-size but except font size every thing is working .

why? here is my code

```
var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

if (!data.IssueTrendsDAO.issueTrendList) {
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("font-size","34px")
    .attr("y", 79)
    .attr("x", 40)
    .attr("dy", ".47em")                        
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "#004669")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("No data to display");
}
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I think you'll find it works if you assign font-size as a style rather than as an attribute.

```
.style("font-size", "34px")
```

(better yet, assign an id or class attribute and set all your styles in CSS)

Comment: It's just strange to me because the example here treats font-size as an attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/font-size#example